# How can I group model atributes

Tags: python, django, models

I have a class for which I'd like to display all models for each `Car` without regularly hiting the database. So I've created a `dict`, but I don't think this is the best solution. How can I solve this problem more professionally?

```
class Car(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + '/' + self.model
```

```
def catatlog(request):

    cars = {}
    all_cars = Car.objects.all().order_by('name')
    for i in all_cars:
        if i.name not in cars.keys():
            cars[i.name] = [i.model]
        else:
            cars[i.name].append(i.model)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'cars':cars})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) instead:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def catatlog(request):
    cars = defaultdict(list)
    for i in Car.objects.all():
        cars[i.name].append(i.model)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'cars':cars})
```